# Leaflet ReactJS Map does not show tile completely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to create a map that is inside of a modal. But the map is only showed partially. I've tried `invalidatingSize()` after node is created but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import L from 'leaflet';

class Mapa extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    createMap(element){
        var map = L.map(element);
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);
        return map;
    }

    setupMap(){
        this.map.setView([this.props.lat, this.props.lon], this.props.zoom);
        this.map.invalidateSize();
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let self = this;
        if (this.props.createMap) {
            this.map = this.props.createMap(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(self));
        } else {
            this.map = this.createMap(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(self));
        }

        this.setupMap();
    }

    render(){
        /*Returns div with id map*/
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your css file look like?  Sometimes you need to set the heigh and width of the map div to 100%.

Comment: try calling `this.map.invalidateSize();` inside a setInterval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I fixed. The code is correct but I didn't add leaflet dependencies correctly. Once I fixed that all worked perfectly. In fact this.map.invalidateSize(); was no necessary.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
    import L from 'leaflet';

    class Mapa extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
            };
        }

        createMap(element){
            var map = L.map(element);
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
            }).addTo(map);
            return map;
        }

        setupMap(){
            this.map.setView([this.props.lat, this.props.lon], this.props.zoom);
        }

        componentDidMount(){
            let self = this;
            if (this.props.createMap) {
                this.map = this.props.createMap(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(self));
            } else {
                this.map = this.createMap(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(self));
            }

            this.setupMap();
        }

        render(){
            /*Returns div with id map*/
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I did this using the `JSS`:

```
import jss from 'jss';
import jssDefault from 'jss-preset-default';

import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

jss.setup(jssDefault());

jss.createStyleSheet({
  '@global': {
    '.leaflet-container': {
      height: '100%',
    },
  },
}).attach();
```

Leaflet uses global CSS classes. So you can just use your global styles using `css-loader`:

`styles.css`:

```
:global {
  .leaflet-container {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

`component.jsx`:

```
import './styles.css';
```

Comment: Thanks for the info I found it very useful but I was having dependencies issues.

Comment: Thank you very much, helped me after hours trying in vain